# openstack: can't launch instance, multiple errors

Tags: debian, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I'm working with Openstack Mitaka, at the point to try launch an instance.

When creating the instance it hangs in ERROR-state , just after built.

I collected the errors from the logs, but so far I don't have a clue where to start.

```
# scheduler

2016-10-06 14:12:14.925 1812 INFO nova.scheduler.host_manager [req-850b181b-0d54-4e35-9f70-24a2f107188c - - - - -] Successfully synced instances from host 'kvm'.
2016-10-06 14:13:45.807 1812 INFO nova.scheduler.filters.retry_filter [req-433b164d-61aa-47d0-bf53-409c0aa8717e ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] Host [u'kvm', u'kvm.js-networks'] fails.  Previously tried hosts: [[u'kvm', u'kvm.js-networks']]
2016-10-06 14:13:45.808 1812 INFO nova.filters [req-433b164d-61aa-47d0-bf53-409c0aa8717e ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] Filter RetryFilter returned 0 hosts
2016-10-06 14:13:45.808 1812 INFO nova.filters [req-433b164d-61aa-47d0-bf53-409c0aa8717e ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] Filtering removed all hosts for the request with instance ID '7378e55a-f4c5-4127-9e3d-504e0f724e61'. Filter results: ['RetryFilter: (start: 1, end: 0)']


# compute

] Cannot find OS information - Reason: (No configuration information found for operating system Empty)
2016-10-06 14:13:43.526 1816 WARNING nova.virt.osinfo [req-433b164d-61aa-47d0-bf53-409c0aa8717e ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] Cannot find OS information - Reason: (No configuration information found for operating system Empty)
2016-10-06 14:13:43.527 1816 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-433b164d-61aa-47d0-bf53-409c0aa8717e ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] [instance: 7378e55a-f4c5-4127-9e3d-504e0f724e61] Creating image
2016-10-06 14:13:45.020 1816 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-433b164d-61aa-47d0-bf53-409c0aa8717e ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] Instance failed network setup after 1 attempt(s)
2016-10-06 14:13:45.020 1816 ERROR nova.compute.manager Traceback (most recent call last):
(...)
2016-10-06 14:13:45.020 1816 ERROR nova.compute.manager     raise exception.PortBindingFailed(port_id=port_id)
2016-10-06 14:13:45.020 1816 ERROR nova.compute.manager PortBindingFailed: Binding failed for port 35790d3d-57fc-4bd3-a1eb-ec8eeb0ead96, please check neutron logs for more information.
2016-10-06 14:13:45.020 1816 ERROR nova.compute.manager
2016-10-06 14:13:45.021 1816 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-433b164d-61aa-47d0-bf53-409c0aa8717e ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] [instance: 7378e55a-f4c5-4127-9e3d-504e0f724e61] Instance failed to spawn
2016-10-06 14:13:45.021 1816 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 7378e55a-f4c5-4127-9e3d-504e0f724e61] Traceback (most recent call last):
(...)
2016-10-06 14:13:45.021 1816 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 7378e55a-f4c5-4127-9e3d-504e0f724e61]     return self._sync_wrapper(fn, *args, **kwargs)
2016-10-06 14:13:45.021 1816 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 7378e55a-f4c5-4127-9e3d-504e0f724e61]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/network/model.py", line 504, in _sync_wrapper
2016-10-06 14:13:45.021 1816 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 7378e55a-f4c5-4127-9e3d-504e0f724e61]     self.wait()


# neutron

P/1.1" 200 706 0.235835
2016-10-06 14:13:43.791 26693 INFO neutron.wsgi [req-2816c0f3-0ca2-42b0-858d-8ea92c18622f ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 - - [06/Oct/2016 14:13:43] "GET /v2.0/security-groups.json?tenant_id=82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 HTTP/1.1" 200 2517 0.208083
2016-10-06 14:13:43.963 26693 INFO neutron.quota [req-eaf4b7af-453a-4804-92c6-515be29a325e fa3c179b03f44d82b31eb7805224a5ac 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] Loaded quota_driver: <neutron.db.quota.driver.DbQuotaDriver object at 0x7f436c1e5750>.
2016-10-06 14:13:44.313 26693 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [req-eaf4b7af-453a-4804-92c6-515be29a325e fa3c179b03f44d82b31eb7805224a5ac 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] Option "rabbit_host" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit" is deprecated for removal.  Its value may be silently ignored in the future.
2016-10-06 14:13:44.314 26693 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [req-eaf4b7af-453a-4804-92c6-515be29a325e fa3c179b03f44d82b31eb7805224a5ac 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] Option "rabbit_userid" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit" is deprecated for removal.  Its value may be silently ignored in the future.
2016-10-06 14:13:44.314 26693 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [req-eaf4b7af-453a-4804-92c6-515be29a325e fa3c179b03f44d82b31eb7805224a5ac 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] Option "rabbit_password" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit" is deprecated for removal.  Its value may be silently ignored in the future.
2016-10-06 14:13:44.327 26693 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [req-eaf4b7af-453a-4804-92c6-515be29a325e fa3c179b03f44d82b31eb7805224a5ac 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] Failed to bind port 35790d3d-57fc-4bd3-a1eb-ec8eeb0ead96 on host kvm for vnic_type normal using segments [{'segmentation_id': None, 'physical_network': u'provider', 'id': u'31ee48b6-3fdd-4b64-b070-418a342414a0', 'network_type': u'flat'}]
2016-10-06 14:13:44.328 26693 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.plugin [req-eaf4b7af-453a-4804-92c6-515be29a325e fa3c179b03f44d82b31eb7805224a5ac 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] Attempt 2 to bind port 35790d3d-57fc-4bd3-a1eb-ec8eeb0ead96
2016-10-06 14:13:44.331 26693 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [req-eaf4b7af-453a-4804-92c6-515be29a325e fa3c179b03f44d82b31eb7805224a5ac 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] Failed to bind port 35790d3d-57fc-4bd3-a1eb-ec8eeb0ead96 on host kvm for vnic_type normal using segments [{'segmentation_id': None, 'physical_network': u'provider', 'id': u'31ee48b6-3fdd-4b64-b070-418a342414a0', 'network_type': u'flat'}]
(...)
2016-10-06 14:13:44.353 26693 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.plugin [req-eaf4b7af-453a-4804-92c6-515be29a325e fa3c179b03f44d82b31eb7805224a5ac 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] Attempt 10 to bind port 35790d3d-57fc-4bd3-a1eb-ec8eeb0ead96
2016-10-06 14:13:44.355 26693 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [req-eaf4b7af-453a-4804-92c6-515be29a325e fa3c179b03f44d82b31eb7805224a5ac 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] Failed to bind port 35790d3d-57fc-4bd3-a1eb-ec8eeb0ead96 on host kvm for vnic_type normal using segments [{'segmentation_id': None, 'physical_network': u'provider', 'id': u'31ee48b6-3fdd-4b64-b070-418a342414a0', 'network_type': u'flat'}]
2016-10-06 14:13:44.565 26693 INFO neutron.wsgi [req-eaf4b7af-453a-4804-92c6-515be29a325e fa3c179b03f44d82b31eb7805224a5ac 97258b120fb044739


# nova api


2016-10-06 14:13:38.472 2428 INFO nova.api.openstack.wsgi [req-6f2e0117-8a31-4527-8b2e-5b3d0b07d0ab ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] HTTP exception thrown: Image not found.
2016-10-06 14:13:38.473 2428 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-6f2e0117-8a31-4527-8b2e-5b3d0b07d0ab ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "GET /v2.1/82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265/images/cirros HTTP/1.1" status: 404 len: 351 time: 0.5511899
2016-10-06 14:13:38.954 2428 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-e940cc62-f584-444b-8a39-8f18da1d4515 ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "GET /v2.1/82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265/images HTTP/1.1" status: 200 len: 753 time: 0.4790039
2016-10-06 14:13:39.421 2428 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-c1b1ea7c-5ade-4517-8e8c-6f518f305fdb ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "GET /v2.1/82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265/images/e04dff63-90f7-481f-b3cb-971e2afdbd9d HTTP/1.1" status: 200 len: 934 time: 0.4649360
2016-10-06 14:13:39.584 2428 INFO nova.api.openstack.wsgi [req-b91e2da6-35d3-4c1e-88fa-0eb288c19768 ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] HTTP exception thrown: Flavor m1.nano could not be found.
2016-10-06 14:13:39.585 2428 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-b91e2da6-35d3-4c1e-88fa-0eb288c19768 ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "GET /v2.1/82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265/flavors/m1.nano HTTP/1.1" status: 404 len: 369 time: 0.1617870
2016-10-06 14:13:39.749 2428 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-6be7140f-aa08-498b-b1ed-58630b5bf3ce ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "GET /v2.1/82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265/flavors HTTP/1.1" status: 200 len: 1644 time: 0.1629810
2016-10-06 14:13:39.915 2428 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-223a823e-79f5-4c64-8249-d442accfe2ea ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "GET /v2.1/82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265/flavors/0 HTTP/1.1" status: 200 len: 673 time: 0.1640809
2016-10-06 14:13:40.269 2428 WARNING stevedore.named [req-433b164d-61aa-47d0-bf53-409c0aa8717e ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] Could not load create_instance
2016-10-06 14:13:42.269 2428 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-433b164d-61aa-47d0-bf53-409c0aa8717e ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "POST /v2.1/82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265/servers HTTP/1.1" status: 202 len: 808 time: 2.1566091
2016-10-06 14:13:42.658 2428 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-028bb9ba-c926-4fd1-bd0e-9ff40e2bf084 ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "GET /v2.1/82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265/servers/7378e55a-f4c5-4127-9e3d-504e0f724e61 HTTP/1.1" status: 200 len: 1541 time: 0.3874989
2016-10-06 14:13:43.271 2428 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-8de3d5a5-156b-4162-85a6-6c844e91a8f5 ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "GET /v2.1/82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265/images/e04dff63-90f7-481f-b3cb-971e2afdbd9d HTTP/1.1" status: 200 len: 934 time: 0.6110601
2016-10-06 14:13:43.509 2428 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-8a7b89d7-d68b-4590-be67-5f01504f1540 ad61cf3ac5334f129bcf81cb90315774 82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "GET /v2.1/82492ac3a6044da7a7714bf988b30265/flavors/0 HTTP/1.1" status: 200 len: 673 time: 0.2342911
2016-10-06 14:13:47.264 2429 INFO nova.api.openstack.wsgi [req-e90f4776-ae07-4a76-a33a-6c305c3ebb4f b6403fd93d3c448dae7ef336f7f7f334 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] HTTP exception thrown: No instances found for any event
2016-10-06 14:13:47.265 2429 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [req-e90f4776-ae07-4a76-a33a-6c305c3ebb4f b6403fd93d3c448dae7ef336f7f7f334 97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959 - - -] 192.168.0.11 "POST /v2.1/97258b120fb04473977ee6bbe9b96959/os-server-external-events HTTP/1.1" status: 404 len: 367 time: 0.1746118
```

Any help is appreciated A LOT :-) !

Best!

W

Answer (score 1):

From the error message:

```
PortBindingFailed: Binding failed for port 35790d3d-57fc-4bd3-a1eb-ec8eeb0ead96
```

Looks like bridge mapping incorrectly was configured.

See please https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux-openstack-platform/7/paged/networking-guide/chapter-14-configure-bridge-mappings